# How can I connect to a second database and still be able to use wp functions like get_post_types()?

Tags: functions, database, wpdb

I have several WordPress sites that I manage where I will need to get post data from one site and display it on another. Ideally I would like to connect to the second site's db and pull the post information using WordPress's functions. For example, when connecting to another site I would like to use the get_post_types() function to pull the post type information from the second site. In the code below I attempted to set the $wpdb variable to the second site's connection but get_post_types() is still returning information from the main site. When I dump the $wpdb after connecting to the second site it looks like it is connected to the second site but WordPress functions relating to the second site don't work.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb_backup = $wpdb;
//dump main site post types
var_dump(get_post_types());
$db = $bos['afs']['db_name'];
$user = $bos['afs']['db_user'];
$password = $bos['afs']['db_pass'];
$host = $bos['afs']['db_host'];
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $password, $db, $host );
wp_set_wpdb_vars();
//dump query (works. results from second site)
var_dump($wpdb->get_results('Query Here'))
//dump second sites post types (doesn't work. results from main site)
var_dump(get_post_types());
//set to original
$wpdb = $wpdb_backup;
```

Is it even possible to get this functionality working?

Comment: If it’s an option, you’re going to have a much easier time with a Multisite. That being said, your specific example of `get_post_types()` has nothing to do with the database and just isn’t going to be possible no matter what you do.

Comment: The sites should definitely be a multisite but they are not unfortunately.

Comment: So post types are not stored in the database. They’re defined in code, so for that function to work you would somehow need to load the code for WordPress and all the plugins from the other website and somehow intercept that at the right moment to extract the post types. As far as I can tell that’s going to be impossible. Let alone being able to just use the core function. It would break just from trying to load WordPress inside WordPress.

Comment: Yes I believe only the post type slug is stored in the DB in this case. However the get_post_types() function returns a WP_Post_Type array/object where some of the info is not stored in the DB.

Comment: Probably a pretty good use-case for the REST API (in this specific case there's even [a post types endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/post-types/))

Comment: REST API isn't a good alternative in this case because most of the sites were created pre block editor so the custom post types on the sites dont have 'show_in_rest' set to true in the post type definition. Only base wp post types like posts, pages, attachments etc are being pulled through the REST API.

Comment: Then [flip on the `show_in_rest` arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/?p=23089#adding-rest-api-support-to-existing-content-types) - conditionally even, if you don't want those posts exposed publicly. Or short-cirtuit it with a `rest_request_before_callbacks` filter. If that is not an option, setting up a new REST endpoint/controller or AJAX handler is still going to be easier than trying to somehow use one installation's PHP APIs to talk to two installations simultaneously, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Where are you running the code in your question?